# How to Make a custom slider using slick slider with thumbnail slider?

Tags: slider, slick.js

I am working on one project which has a slick slider. I want to make a custom slick slider same as https://www.masterclass.com Where once you click on thumbs it will redirect you to somewhere and it will change main slider images while you click on arrows it will change the sliders. 
I have gone through this website http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ but it is not what i am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and do a find for slider syncing, it will show a demo that functions very similar to what you are describing.

To have the slide redirect on click, in the HTML, make the slide(s) content links with the href pointing to wherever you want to go.

Unless I'm missing your intent, this is almost exactly the slider behavior shown on https://www.masterclass.com.

Let me know if this helps! Good Luck!